# lstlisting in table, where does the extra space come from and how to get rid of it?

Tags: tables, listings

I am trying to place and `lstlisting` in a table but I am get some extra space that I don't want and don't know where it is coming from:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

    \lstset{ language=bash, 
             breaklines=true,
             postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
             frame=single }

    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=foo2bar]
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{rp{0.72\linewidth}}

Foo: & foo2bar \\
Command: & \begin{lstlisting}
sed 's/foo/bar/g' ../fooer.foo.txt > fooer.foo.txt.foo2bar.bar.txt
\end{lstlisting} \\
Bar: & \\

        \end{tabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Marked with cyan in the image below:

[image]

Where do they come from and more importantly how do I get rid of them? :)

Comment: `[aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt]` makes it a bit better.

Comment: Yea `aboveskip=-8pt,belowskip=-12pt` is my hack for the moment...

Comment: Putting inside a minipage also helps.

Answer (score 6):

I would use tcolorbox also for the listings: it has much more and much more powerful keys to adjust the look. E.g.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

    \lstset{ language=bash,
             breaklines=true,
             postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
             %frame=single
              }

    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=foo2bar]
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{rp{0.72\linewidth}}
         Foo: & foo2bar \\
         Command: &
\begin{tcblisting}{sharp corners, listing only, baseline=\dimexpr\csname tcb@height\endcsname-\normalbaselineskip\relax,after={}}
sed 's/foo/bar/g' ../fooer.foo.txt > fooer.foo.txt.foo2bar.bar.txt
\end{tcblisting} 
         \\
         Bar: & \\

        \end{tabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, what all those different commands do?